# What are the advantages and disadvantages of leaders using telephone calls instead of video calls?

Tags: technology

In recent years, the use of video calls has become increasingly popular, leading me to question why leaders still opt for telephone calls instead. There are several reasons why video calls should be the preferred method of communication, the most compelling being that it is almost like sitting face to face. Additionally, demonstrations can be more effectively conveyed through video calls, and more people can be included in the conversation.

So why aren't video calls the default for communication between governments?

Comment: I would think it's more resilient/robust, as less data needs to be transmitted. Also, if phone has worked so far, why bother changing? OTOH, how do we know they're not video calls, but are only reported as 'phone calls'?

Comment: False premise.  They use both.  So do you, I'm sure.  Unless you mean the Moscow-Washington "red phone", which isn't really a phone...

Comment: Leaders tweet "telephonic conversation...", so I think they use telephone. Sometimes they distinctly mention video conference. For example during Covid, many summits were held using video conference.

Comment: Telephones are generally more reliable, especially over very long distances.  Nobody wants to deal with microphone or webcam problems, lag, freezes, etc, when you just need to have a quick conversation.  These are the same reasons everyone uses to decide whether to call or video call...

Comment: Sometimes, call go on for long duration, say at least 40 mins. Also, I am sure the staff would handle the technical issues in advance. And being the government, they can arrange a faster mode of internet.

Comment: The telephone lines between leaders seem to be confidential. However I don´t think this question can be answered with facts.

Comment: I guess the leaders may be surrounded by high-level diplomats who may hint them about the most satisfactory replies by listening to the talks on a loud speaker..Such things would be awkard on a video call..

Answer (score 4):

You're ignoring a key factor here: whose system do you use?

Every video chat system requires you to install software on a device in your network. Do you want to install their software? Do you think they'll install your software? Do you want to trust Company X in that country to not be used to install malware or spyware on your device?

Phones don't require you to install software. In fact, for a very long time, phones didn't use any software at all.

Video also introduces a new way to leak information. A careless memo left on a desk. An object in the background. Video can contain a wealth of information you might not want to share.

Comment: But they do video call anyway, howsoever rare it be.